# Joomla Code highlighter extension issue

Tags: php, joomla, pre, codehighlighter

I've a Joomla site that I am designing for college. The user should be able to post tutorials relating to Android programming.

http://www.jciadt.com/cms/ca

Currently I am trying to get the articles posted by users successfully display snippets of code.

I looked into using this extension:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

And it looked like a viable option, however I am getting undesired results in my articles when I include code snippets:

see below:

http://www.jciadt.com/cms/ca/index.php/tutorials/beginner/9-layout-ui-options-part-i

Scroll to bottom of page to nested lists section to see what I mean.

does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: You should probably contact the developer of this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following approach to determine what is happening:

**#1** Compare the content, i.e. the original source code to make sure it's formatted correctly. If you're referring to the indenting of the `<Button` element and the various `android:` attributes as the problem, one thing I've noticed is that in [the page linked](http://www.jciadt.com/cms/ca/index.php/tutorials/beginner/9-layout-ui-options-part-i) they have the wrong number of spaces proceeding them compared to the previous lines. All previous lines appear to use the standard `4 spaces` per `tab` stop, the last set use 6 spaces.

When I copy your code into this answer I see the same problem, so I would guess it's in your original code.

```xml
<LinearLayout ... >
  <TextView ... />
  <EditText ... />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  >   

<Button
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/setName" />
    <Button
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/clearName" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**#2** If the content is correct, then given how many different [code highlighter extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/code-display) are on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) ([JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/)), I would try several different ones. If they all have the same problem then you've probably missed something in your code sample.